# MySQL Stored Procedures - Adding integer variable to date returns null

Tags: mysql, procedure, addition

I am writing my first mysql procedure.  I have a `date` variable and 2 integer variables.  I am multiplying the two integer variables and adding the resultant integer to the `date` variable.

For example:

```
pint=6;
noftimes=3
sdate=2020-05-05
totDays=pint*noftimes
edate=2020-05-05+totDays
```

I am able to multiple `pint*noftimes` but not add `sdate+totDays`.  Whereas If I add `sdate+10` then I am getting a correct incremental date value.  The following is my procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`pattu`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getFieldWorkDates`(IN `p_id` INT, OUT `totDays` INT, OUT `edate` DATE)
BEGIN
DECLARE noftimes int;
DECLARE pint int;
DECLARE sdate DATE;
DECLARE tdays int;
SELECT startDate into sdate from projects where idprojects=p_id;
SELECT projectDuration into noftimes from projects where idprojects=p_id;
SELECT recFreq into pint from projects where idprojects=p_id;
SET totDays=pint*noftimes;
SET edate = sdate+(pint*noftimes);

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I execute this, I am getting the message, your query has been executed successfully. 0 rows affected

Comment: @Akina Thank you...it worked.  I can accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `SET edate = sdate+(pint*noftimes);`

You cannot add integer to date. Use DATE_ADD() function.

---

```
CREATE 
DEFINER=pattu@localhost
PROCEDURE getFieldWorkDates ( IN p_id INT, 
                              OUT totDays INT, 
                              OUT edate DATE)
SELECT recFreq * projectDuration, 
       startDate + INTERVAL recFreq * projectDuration DAY 
INTO totDays, 
     edate 
FROM projects 
WHERE idprojects=p_id;
```